# Can we run multiple jobs in parallel having just one GoCD agent?

Tags: go-cd, thoughtworks-go

I have installed `GoCD server`. And Installed one `GoCD Agent`.

Now i created a new pipeline : Pipeline1

Created one stage : Stage1

Now two jobs: Job1 and Job2

As i am having one GoAgent, does these two jobs will be executed parallely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, one agent only runs one job at a time.

You can, however, [run multiple agents in parallel on the same machine](https://docs.gocd.org/current/advanced_usage/admin_install_multiple_agents.html), so that you can execute several jobs in parallel.